# film.stackexchange.com should redirect to the site

Tags: feature-request

If you go to http://film.stackexchange.com/ , you get a 404 page.

I believe you should be redirected to https://movies.stackexchange.com/ .

(Personally, I often type the former rather than the latter when looking for this site.)

**edit:** @NapoleonWilson suggests a redirect from http://films.stackexchange.com/ . That's also a good idea, and I see no reason why it shouldn't be both.

Comment: `films` would probably be more consistent, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I don't think so, because it's a collective noun, unlike movies. But `films.stackexchange.com` should _also_ redirect to the site IMHO.

Comment: Personally, I agree with @NapoleonWilson

Comment: @taylor.2317: I also agree with him, in the sense that `films` should redirect to the site. My request doesn't contradict his suggestion :-)

Comment: I am not in favour of synonyms for site names unlike synonyms for tags.

Comment: Why type at all? There could be a dozen such aliases and all of them hardly useful.